# HTML5 reset button: change initial values after a save/submit

Tags: javascript, html

Using HTML5's reset button I can easily reset the form to it's "initial values" (the ones when the form was created/loaded).

What happens is, I submit the form using ajax, that means the entity/data is now updated. So, is there a way to tell the browser that those submited values are now the "initial values", so if the user hits the reset button it does not reset to the old values?

Thanks!

[edited]
We have standard forms for our applications, with a Save/Cancel button on them. If you save the entity, we remain in the form. We're using Aurelia Framework with Syncfusion for our UI.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know much about Aurelia or Syncfusion, but an HTML `reset` input will reset every input element in the form to its `value` attribute. So if you use `setAttribute` to replace the element's `value` attribute with the new value, the reset button will use that one as the "initial" value from then on.

Comment: becomes harder when you use two "non compatible" frameworks... anyway, that's exactly what I needed! Thanks